# fprintf stops working after performing external edit

Tags: linux, printf

I have a c++ program, A, that opens a file for append using fopen(file_name,"a");  The file is written to via fprintf().  Everything works fine until I edit the file from another session (e.g. using vim); this is necessary to do during debugging.  After saving the file program from the vim session, A stops writing to the file.  I've checked and the fprintf() is working fine as far as I can tell; as expected the return value equals the number of bytes written, but nothing shows up in the file.  Can someone explain why this occurring?  Specifically is there a way for program A to detect this situation and 'do something about it; e.g. close and reopen the file.

Comment: You sure you're not saving in Vim after the edit, or that Vim is opening a swap / recovery file when you reopen to check?

Comment: Related: [When editing an existing file with VIM: will it replace or change that file](http://superuser.com/questions/420478/when-editing-an-existing-file-with-vim-will-it-replace-or-change-that-file)

Comment: After the edit I exit vim using 'wq' and do not reopen the file again.  Viewing the log file being written I see no new entries after the vim edit.  Why/How would this affect the open file handle in program A?

Comment: This only seems to happen with vim.  If I use a different editor, including some graphic ones, I do not have this problem.  So apparently vim is doing something 'different' when it saves the file.